# Why can't iron router find this template, that i've clearly defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I keep getting this error:

> Couldn't find a template named "layoutSimple" or "layoutSimple". Are you sure you defined it?

Route code:

```js
Router.onBeforeAction(OnBeforeActions.loginRequired, {
  except: ['login', 'logout']
});

Router.onBeforeAction(OnBeforeActions.adminRequired, {
  except: ['login', 'logout']
});

Router.route("main", {
  template: 'Dashboard',
  path: '/'
});

Router.route("login", {layoutTemplate: 'layoutSimple'});
Router.route("logout", {layoutTemplate: 'layoutSimple'});
Router.route('adminRequired', {layoutTemplate: 'layoutSimple'});
```

Template code:

```html
<template name="layoutSimple">

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper sidebar-collapse">

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      {{>yield}}

    </section>
  </div>

</template>
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation ? https://guide.meteor.com/routing.html#rendering-routes

Comment: yeah, this is a project i inherited.

Comment: what directory is the template code in?